# AdMob - Disable request onPause()

Tags: android, admob, onresume, onpause, adview

I have read few articles on trying to stop adView when the app is hidden/minimised but this crashes my app.

This is my code, adView.LoadAd... and adView.stopLoading both crashes the app on startup.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (AdViewStarted = true) {
            adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (AdViewStarted = true) {
            adView.destroy();
        }
    }

    [...]

    public class AdMob extends Activity {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER,"12345678901234567890");
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.adView);
            layout.addView(adView);
            adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
            AdViewStarted = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            if (adView != null) {
                adView.destroy();
            }
            super.onDestroy();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `AdViewStarted`? A Boolean? Checking a boolean in if is done with two equals `==`!

Comment: Yes it's a boolean, thanks for the reply, it's solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace the if statements, you have to use two equals instead of one. Correct would be

```
if (AdViewStarted == true) {
        adView.destroy();
}
```

or better

```
if (AdViewStarted) {
        adView.destroy();
}
```

By the win, variable names are starting with a lowercase char.

Also, what are you trying in your `onCreate`?

This is correct (I think, if not, show me the layout xml file and LogCat):

```
LinearLayout adView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.adView);
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
AdViewStarted = true;
```

Comment: Oh wow. I can't believe I missed the == lol I keep doing that. I'm self teaching Java, the scripting language I used before only needed 1 = sign so I keep forgetting. Thanks :)

Comment: I have nothing AdMob related in the onCreate() for the MainActivity. This is the xml:
<com.google.ads.AdView
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
ads:adUnitId="1234567890123456890"
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />

This is why the ads start automatically

Comment: What about the Activity `AdMob`?

Comment: What about it? I don't call it. It gets called automatically... somehow... I'm not sure. I added the AdMob activity to main activity. Modified layout in xml, added the packages to Manifest and linked the Google...jar file. That's it, and it works.